# How to teach PHPStorm your own framework?

Tags: php, frameworks, phpstorm

There is this app written in an in-house developed PHP framework. The framework is basically using /pages folder where there are controller and view files:

`/pages/PageName.php` (a controller)
`/pages/Pagename.phtml` (a view)

Controller files contain classes that contain methods that set up variables for their views. For example, this line in controller's method sets variable `$title` to its view:

```
$this->set('title', 'my cool title');
```

Currently, when I ctrl click a variable in a view, PHPStorm tries to guess where this variable is set but unfortunately it gets it completely wrong. For example ctrl clicking `$title` in `Budget.phtml` does not open `Budget.php` and jump to aforementioned `$this->set('title'...` row but opens ObjectBookingRows.phtml (another view which is totally unrelated) where another variable also called `$title` happens to be temporarily used (written).

I've seen plugins for Laravel and other frameworks but since this app is not using any of them, is it possible to "teach" PHPStorm how my project works? What are my options?

Comment: Please provide some simple example with few files (small test project) where there such situation would occur. Right now it's not clear what is going on (at least for me).

Comment: I made a Youtube video on what's going on: http://youtu.be/naQsIFbuh6c.

Comment: I see -- thnx for video. Well -- IDE behaves correctly considering the situation -- it jumps to the global `$title` variable which is defined elsewhere as it simply does not know anything about your framework (i.e. the fact that all variables here got created just for this view in corresponding controller). The only way to correctly resolve such references is to code plugin for this custom framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need plugin for this situation.

P.S. I can help you and create simple plugin.

Comment: Could you expand this answer to describe how one would create such a plugin? That would help others too.

Comment: you can download plugin - https://github.com/funivan/phpstorm-demo-variablegotohandler/releases/tag/0.0.1 

Video link: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVy2MJGJ6LM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVy2MJGJ6LM)

Comment: Thank you!!! It works as I wanted! Looking at the source I see that it is a lot more complicated than I expected. Could you point to any good tutorials on how to make such plugins?

Comment: Sometimes it is easy to write code than explain. I will try to do that, but i don`t promise.

Comment: I tried to load this plugin into PS138.2001 but PS crashed while doing that. Here's crash log: http://pastebin.com/G7TNf16V

Comment: Try to compile in your machine. I use intellij idea community edition. (In phpstorm 8.0.2 #139.584 all is ok - latest eap version)